# XML/XSLT Transform Logic / If Statement / Hide Certain Line

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am having problems with formating the display of the XML into HTML with XSL.

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Send_Email>
<Send_Email_lookupID>HIDE_REJECT</Send_Email_lookupID>
<Error_Message>REJECT1</Error_Message> 
<Error_Message>REJECT2</Error_Message>   
<Error_Message>REJECT3</Error_Message>   
</Send_Email>
```

And the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>Result</h2>
<table border="1">
<xsl:for-each select="/Send_Email">
<xsl:if test="not(/Send_Email_lookupID)">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="*"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This line is always static and should be hidden:

```
<Send_Email_lookupID>HIDE_REJECT</Send_Email_lookupID>
```

The next set of lines may be different everytime, but all need to be displayed.

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks in Advance.

---

Update - Correct Solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>Result</h2> 
<table border="1">
<xsl:for-each select="Send_Email/*[local-name()!='Send_Email_lookupID']"> 
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want a table with one row for each error message - than what you are looking for is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <html> 
      <body> 
        <h2>Result</h2> 
        <table border="1"> 
          <xsl:for-each select="Send_Email/Error_Message"> 
            <tr> 
              <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td> 
            </tr> 
          </xsl:for-each> 
        </table> 
      </body> 
    </html> 
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`/Send_Email_lookupID` matches a root element because it starts with `/` - but in your XML the element with that name is not the root one.

If you don't want to match just `Error_Message` but EVERY element under `Send_Email` except `Send_Email_lookupID` use:

```
          <xsl:for-each select="Send_Email/*[local-name()!='Send_Email_lookupID']">
```

that means 'all the elements under `Send_Email` except those named `Send_Email_lookupID`.

Note also that `<xsl:value-of select="*"/>` outputs the text contained inside all sub-elements of the current node - whereas `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` outputs the text contained in the current node - that is what we want in this case.

Comment: use <xsl:for-each select="Send_Email/*[.!='HIDE_REJECT']"> if you want to hide based on the value of the node.

Comment: It still returns null for me. I'll post the new XSLT in the original question.

Comment: Sorry - typo - it should be `select="."` - I fixed my answer